# How to avoid SQL injection in Rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-injection, controllers, hash

In my Controllers I'm using many **find_by_sql()** stuff, and to avoid SQL injection I'm building my SQL statements as **hashes** as follows

```
Beneficiary.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM beneficiaries WHERE project_id=? AND cso_id IN(SELECT user_id FROM user_projects INNER JOIN users ON  user_projects.user_id=users.id)",params[:id]])
```

Is it enough to avoid SQL injection? or need more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It's enough, you use placeholder for parameters, there is no SQL injection problem.

Comment: Sorry, actually what you mean by "Place Holder"? can you please elaborate?

Comment: check here, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement, prepared_statement don't have sql injection problem.